# project euler #4 largest palindrome using python

Tags: python, palindrome

```
product=1
ans=[]
for i in range(100,999):
    for j in range(100,999):
        product=i*j
        temp=product
        while(product>0):
            rev=1
            dig=product%10
            rev=rev*10+dig
            product=product//10
        if(temp==rev):
            ans.append(rev)
print(ans)
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong in this above problem. I am not getting the final answer

Q) A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Comment: Project Euler specifically tells you that if you can't solve it, you can't solve it.

Comment: A one-liner just for the fun of it: `print(sorted([i*j for i in range(999, 99, -1) for j in range(i, 99, -1) if str(i*j) == (str(i*j))[::-1]])[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

i think you misunderstood the question from what i am seeing in your code. 
Question:
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
so in this case the palindromic is 9009 as when your read it forwards and backwards it is still 9009.
what the question is asking is find two 3 digit numbers when multiplied together it will give you the largest palindrome.

as the largest palindrome which is possible for this is 913 x 993 = 906609

so your code would be simplified to this.

```
ans = 0
for i in range(100, 999):
    for j in range(100, 999):
        product = str(i * j)
        if int(product) > ans:  # check if the value is bigger then the last palindrome.
            if product == product[::-1]:  # check if it is a palindrome.
                ans = int(product)
print(ans)
```

thou from the question i would actually reverse the range(1000,100,-1)
as since we are finding the largest it would be better to work backwards on it.